# ASP MVC - Random session timeouts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this:

```
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
```

and this:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" cookieless="UseCookies" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" timeout="15">
```

And my session is timing out at random times, I can be viewing page after page and then get logged out, what could cause that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a distinction between ASP.NET Session:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" cookieless="UseCookies" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" timeout="15">
```

and forms authentication:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/account/login" timeout="2800" />
</authentication>
```

The ASP.NET Session is by default stored in the memory of the web server. The problem with this is that your application could be recycled or brought down by the web server at any time and the session will be lost. This could happen for example if your server hits some CPU or memory thresholds and is pretty much out of your control. If tyou want to store something into the ASP.NET session in a reliable way you should ensure that you are using an out-of-process state (such as `StateServer` or `SqlServer`). Here's an article about the [`various session state modes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Forms authentication on the other hand is used to track your authenticated users with cookies. They are not persisted on the server and not suffering from the same limitations as the ASP.NET Session. If you ever decide to use the ASP.NET Session in your application you should make sure that its timeout is the same as the timeout for the forms authentication cookie and that you are using an out of proc persistence state.

Comment: `timeout="2800"` this is in seconds? I had this set up to 15, and i thought it was in minutes?

Comment: Once again, do not confuse ASP.NET Session with Forms Authentication. Those are 2 completely different things. But yes, the timeout property of the [`<forms>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1d3t3c61(v=vs.90).aspx) node is in minutes. And the `timeout` property of the [`<sessionState>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.80).aspx) node is also in minutes.

Comment: Well, yes I am aware of the differences between session and forms auth, but, it is still wierd, if I had forms auth timeout set to 15, why could I stay logged in for 5 minutes (no activity) without being thrown out?

Comment: Why would you be thrown out? You should stay inactive for more than 15 minutes if you want that to happen. It will also depend on whether you activated sliding expiration or not. If you activated it, if the user performs a request to the server, the timeout period is renewed. But it's a bad idea to activate sliding expiration from a security point of view anyway.

Comment: What? I had no idea something like sliding expiration exists, I thought that behavior (refreshing timeout on user requests) is by default. Why is it bad?

Comment: It's bad because the forms authentication cookie is renewed automatically on each request meaning that if a hacker gets hold of this cookie he could renew it indefinitely, leaving him all the time in the world to do nasty things with his victim. If the cookie had fixed expiration period, then the damage might somehow be limited because the cookie will be valid only for a certain amount of time.

Comment: Okay, then what about session? If I set forms auth to 30 minutes, and session to 15 minutes, will it renew automatically (session)?

Comment: The default value of the `slidingExpiration` attribute is `true`.

Comment: Watch out if you add more threads to your app pool (by turning it into a web garden) or move to a web farm, session does not automatically share between separate web garden threads or web farm servers.  This can cause odd sign outs as well.